# Printing out a Polynomial that is Double Wrapped inside of a Class

Tags: c++

I've been tasked with creating a C++ class called Polynomial that applies different mathematical formulas to the Polynomial. I was given 4 separate bits of code that are a requirement to use along with the rest of my program and I don't quite understand how I am suppose go about using these wrappers throughout my functions. Such as in my print function and accessing the polynomial hidden multiple layers in.

Premade 1:

```
#ifndef __GUARDED_ARRAY_H__
#define __GUARDED_ARRAY_H__

using namespace std;

typedef int ItemType;

const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 500;

//
// GuardedArray
// - A wrapper class for C++ arrays to make array access safe.
//   Specifically, initialization is guaranteed, and assertions are
    //   in place to detect array index out of bound errors in array member
//   accesses.
//

class GuardedArray {
public:

    // Purpose: Initializes array elements to zeros
    GuardedArray();

    // Purpose: Initializes all array elements to a given value
    GuardedArray(ItemType x);

    // Purpose: Read array element at index i
    ItemType read(unsigned i) const;

    // Purpose: Write x into array element at index i.
    void write(unsigned i, ItemType x);

private:

    ItemType array[MAX_LENGTH];

};

#endif
```

Premade 2:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "polynomial.h"
#include "guarded_array.h"
#include "managed_array.h"

GuardedArray::GuardedArray() {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
}

GuardedArray::GuardedArray(ItemType x) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        array[i] = x;
}

ItemType GuardedArray::read(unsigned i) const {
    assert(i < MAX_LENGTH);
    return array[i];
}

void GuardedArray::write(unsigned i, ItemType x) {
    assert(i < MAX_LENGTH);
    array[i] = x;
}
```

Premade 3:

```
#ifndef __MANAGED_ARRAY_H__
#define __MANAGED_ARRAY_H__

#include "guarded_array.h"

using namespace std;

//
// ManagedArray
// - A wrapper class for C++ arrays to facilitate insertion and removal of
//   array elements.
// - Every instance of ManagedArray has a size that can be increased
//   until the maximum capacity MAX_LENGTH is reached.
//

class ManagedArray {
public:

    // Purpose: Initializes array to have zero size.
    ManagedArray();

    // Purpose: Initializes array to a given size.  All array elements
    ManagedArray(unsigned N);

    // Purpose: Initializes array to a given size.  All array elements
    //          are initialized to x.
    ManagedArray(unsigned N, ItemType x);

    // Purpose: Return the current size of the array.
    unsigned size() const;

    // Purpose: Read array element at index i
    ItemType read(unsigned i) const;

    // Purpose: Write x into array element at index i.
    void write(unsigned i, ItemType x);

    // Purpose: Insert an element into the array.
    void insert(unsigned i, ItemType x);

    // Purpose: Remove an element from the array.
    void remove(unsigned i);

private:

    unsigned count;
    GuardedArray array;

};

#endif
```

Premade 4:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "polynomial.h"
#include "guarded_array.h"
#include "managed_array.h"

ManagedArray::ManagedArray() : array() {
    count = 0;
}

ManagedArray::ManagedArray(unsigned N) : array() {
    assert(N <= MAX_LENGTH);
    count = N;
}

ManagedArray::ManagedArray(unsigned N, ItemType x) : array(x) {
    assert(N <= MAX_LENGTH);
    count = N;
}

unsigned ManagedArray::size() const {
    return count;
}

ItemType ManagedArray::read(unsigned i) const {
    assert(i < count);
    return array.read(i);
}

void ManagedArray::write(unsigned i, ItemType x) {
    assert(i < count);
    array.write(i, x);
}

void ManagedArray::insert(unsigned i, ItemType x) {
    assert(i <= count && count < MAX_LENGTH);
    for (unsigned j = count; j > i; j--)
        array.write(j, array.read(j - 1));
    array.write(i, x);
    count++;
}

void ManagedArray::remove(unsigned i) {
    assert(i < count && count > 0);
    for (unsigned j = i; j < count - 1; j++)
        array.write(j, array.read(j + 1));
    count--;
}
```

And this here is my own code that must be altered to accommodate for the above code:

```
#include "polynomial.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Polynomial poly1;

    poly1.print();

    /* Calculate all of these:
    The zero polynomial.
    The degree of the zero polynomial.
    The value of the zero polynomial when x = 1.
    The polynomial P(x) = -1 + 3x^2 - 2x^5.
    The degree of P(x).
    The value of P(1) and P(-2).
    The polynomial Q(x) = 1 + x^3 + 2x^5.
    The polynomial P(x) +Q(x).
    The polynomial P(x) - Q(x).
    The polynomial 4P(x).
    The polynomial x^2Q(x).
    The polynomial P(x)Q(x).
*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include "managed_array.h"

using namespace std;

//
// Polynomial class
//
//Purpose- To hold and calculate specific polynomial equations
//
//Parameter(s)- 
//              -None OR
//              -An array of coefficients and the size of the array OR
//              -An instance of Polynomial to copy into a new instance
//Precondition(s)- In the array/array size constructor the last element of the array must be non-zero
//              
//Returns- N/A
//
//Side Effect- Holds all functions required to intialize, hold, and calculate specific polynomial equations
//
//
class Polynomial
{
private:
    ManagedArray polynomial;

public:

    Polynomial(); //Default constructor
    /*
        second constructor takes an integer array and an integer array size as arguments, and initializes the target Polynomial
        instance with coefficients identical to the elements of the array
        A precondition for this operation is that the last element of the array must be non-zero, or else the array size is zero.
    */
    Polynomial(int array[], const unsigned int size);
    /*
        A third constructor expects a Polynomial instance as its sole argument, and initializes the target Polynomial 
        instance with coefficients identical to those in the argument Polynomial.
    */
    //Polynomial();

    //Purpose- Apply the Polynomial function to an integer argument.That is, compute the value of the Polynomial for a given value of x.
    void evaluate();

    //Purpose- An arithmetic addition operation that adds one instance of Polynomial to another.
    void add(const Polynomial& poly2);

    //Purpose- An arithmetic subtraction operation that subtracts one instance of Polynomial by another.
    void subtract();

    //Purpose- An arithmetic multiplication operation that multiplies one instance of Polynomial by another.
    void multiply();

    //Purpose- An arithmetic multiplication operation that multiplies an instance of Polynomial by an integer.
    //void multiply();

    //Purpose- An arithmetic multiplication operation that multiplies an instance of Polynomial by a polynomial of the form x^k for some non-negative integer k
    void raiseDegree();

    //Purpose- A Boolean operation that compares two instances of Polynomial to determine if they are identical.
    bool equal();

    //Purpose- Get the degree of a Polynomial instance.
    int getDegree();

    //Purpose- Retrieve the coefficient of the term x^k in a Polynomial instance, given a non-negative integer k.
    int getCoefficient();

    //Purpose- Print a Polynomial instance in a user-friendly format.
    void print() const;

    //The polynomial (-3 + 4x - 7x^3) should be printed in the following format.- 3 + 4 x - 7 x^3

};

#endif
```

cpp:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include "managed_array.h"
#include "guarded_array.h"

unsigned int i;

Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    ManagedArray();
    GuardedArray();
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int array[], const unsigned int size)
{
    ManagedArray(size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int temp = array[i];
        GuardedArray(temp);
    }
}

//Polynomial::Polynomial()
//{
//
//}

void Polynomial::evaluate()
{

}

void Polynomial::add(const Polynomial& poly2)
{

}

void Polynomial::subtract()
{

}

void Polynomial::multiply()
{

}

//void Polynomial::multiply()
//{
//
//}

void Polynomial::raiseDegree()
{

}

bool Polynomial::equal()
{
    return false;
}

int Polynomial::getDegree()
{
    return -1;
}

int Polynomial::getCoefficient()
{
    return -1;
}

void Polynomial::print() const
{

}
```

Comment: Just a tip: don't use double underscores in your macros and variable names, they're reserved for the compiler's use! A simple `GUARDED_ARRAY_H` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to deal with data member `polynomial` in class `Polynomial`, which represents the coefficients of the polynomial.

For example, `polynomial.read(2)` should return the coefficient of the term x^2

To get you started, in *polynomial.cpp*

```
Polynomial::Polynomial()
    :polynomial() {}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int array[], const int size)
    :polynomial(size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        polynomial.write(i, array[i]);
}

double Polynomial::evaluate(double x) const
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < polynomial.size(); ++i)
        sum += polynomial.read(i) * pow(x, i);
    return sum;
}
```